# Bricked on-board debugger BMD-340 evaluation board (Rigado)

Tags: flash, segger-jlink

I probably bricked my BMD340 evaluation board on-board debugger, which uses JLINK. I can only call the bootloader when pressing reset while power on. Is there a possibility to flash again the on-board debugger? I fear the firmware is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with the same interface interface MCU firmware image as the regular NRF52840 DK. Download it and put it on the board in bootloader mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).